# Is something preventing Mary from finding out who she really is?

Tags: ib

Mary knows that she lives in a weird painting world and that outside of this world, there is another one where she might find her "father."

However she is not aware of the fact that

> she is not a real person and a painting. Specifically Guertena's final work.

When she reads the art book, something messes with

> [her entry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXNmw.png)

making it [unreadable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kd3uW.png).

Similarly, that entry gets swapped with the one for "Marvelous Night," if Ib, Garry, and Mary read it when they are together.

> However when Garry reads the entry and find out that she is not human, the "Strained Ear" hears Garry read her entry, and the "Tattletale" then "tells" Mary the secret... However she momentarily [goes crazy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uf83K.png), but [returns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4EAS8.png) to her old self soon afterwards, without the knowledge of what she had just heard.

In one of the endings...

> "A Painting's Demise," where she leave Ib and Garry behind and just tries to leave the Fabricated World... something stops her.

Is there some unknown third pulling the strings? If so, who is it and why are they doing this?

[image: Mary]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears the Mary is in a state of constant denial. She wants to be a real person and refuses to accept the fact that she is a painting. We know that she wants to be real because of how her one wish is to leave the gallery and experience the fun things of the real world. That is why the words are considered unreadable, she really does not want to read them.

When she tries to leave the Fabricated World she is unable, because inside of her room she wrote a small journal.  Inside that journal in says that she cannot leave on her own. The only way for to leave his to take the place of another, which is why she is able to leave in the "Together Forever" ending. She took the place of Garry. Because she did not take the place of anyone she could not escape.

The person who "killed" her at the end of "A Paintings Demise" is probably her father or some other piece of art like "Mistake".

It might have been her father because of the last things she says. While Mary is pleadingly choking out for help she ends with the word Father. It is possible that she was asking for help from her her father Guertena, or it could be that she realized at the very end that Guertena was the one who was going to punish her. This is further supported by the messages that appear as the lights slowly dim. They talk about how Mary has been a bad girl and they sound like something a father says to a disobedient daughter. These were probably Guertena's way of scolding Mary because she disobeyed and tried to leave the gallery.